# EditText, OnTouchListener and setSelection doesn't work on first touch

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-edittext

I've got the following code which fires every time my "redTime" EditText is touched.

```
redTime.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("click", "onMtouch");
            redTime.setSelection(redTime.getText().length());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It is meant to keep the cursor on the right side of the EditText upon every touch. The problem is that the line containing the "setSelection" method doesn't work upon the FIRST touch of the control. That is, if another control has focus, and I touch the "redTime" control for the first time, the method is fired, but the cursor remains at the location I touched (not the right side).

How do I know the listener fires? The "Log.i" call works, but not the cursor change. I suspect the "setSelection" call is working, but some later event is negating it.

I tried a few things. I tried consuming the event by returning TRUE in the listener. Didn't work. I tried repeating the "setSelection" call in OnTouchListener, and OnFocusChanged as well. Still doesn't work.

I almost forgot. Here is the XML for the control in question.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/redEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:text="@string/zeroTime"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="32sp" >
        </EditText>
```

Comment: Where are you adding the OnTouchListener?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm adding it in the OnCreate method.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue recently and couldn't get anything to work, so ended up doing this:

```
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setSelection(getText().length());
                }
            }, 50);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It seems that it is some bug with editText, because I had type decimal, it worked normally, but then changed to number and it stopped setting selector normally

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me, only instead of postDelayed I used hander.postDelayed, and handler is android.os.Handler

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the error do something like this:

```
yourEditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                yourEditText.setFocusable(true);
                yourEditText.requestFocus();
                yourEditText.setSelection(emailEditText.getText().length());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.performClick();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
redTime.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("click", "onMtouch");
        redTime.setFocusable(true);
        redTime.requestFocus();
        redTime.setSelection(redTime.getText().length());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Before you call `setSelection`, that way `redTime` will have the focus when you do the selection.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! But I'm not sure where I would put this. Where did you mean for this code to go, please?

Comment: @mcsilvio There you go!

Comment: After trying this, it does not appear to work. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the edittext as like below

```
   <EditText    
    android:id="@+id/from"
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:hint="@string/pickup_location"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"  
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"    
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Set the ontouch listener in your activity

```
 EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et); et.setOnTouchListener(this)



@Override   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {     
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)     
    switch (v.getId()) {            
            case R.id.from:
                //do your action
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method:

```
redTime.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){  //check the event
                 redTime.requestFocus();  //keep focus on the EditText(redTime)
                 redTime.selectAll();  //select all text
            }

        }
        return true;
});
```

Comment: this does not even compile