# TextView is not selectable with ontouchListener

Tags: java, android, textview, ontouchlistener

I have implemented ontouchListener in my activity to detect swipes left and right. However, enabling this feature stopped me from being able to make my text selectable and accordingly getting the default android text selection cursor, menu.

After many trials, now i can perfectly call the onLongClick() method when long clicking the textView. However, still the text is not selectable. also, whenever I disable the swipe detection, the Text selection works perfectly.

```
public class PreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

TextView question;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);
    question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    question.setTextSize(TextViewSize);
    question.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    question.setLongClickable(true);
    question.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    View prev_act = (View) findViewById(R.id.question);
    prev_act.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        @Override public void onSwipeLeft() {
            if(RowIndex>0){
                Qtitle = ListItems.get(RowIndex-1);
                Query();
                //text = Query();

            //question.setText(text);
            questionSC.scrollTo(0,0);
            RowIndex--;
             }
        }
        @Override public void onSwipeRight() {
            if(RowIndex<ListItems.size()-1){
                Qtitle = ListItems.get(RowIndex+1);
                Query();
                //text = Query();

                //question.setText(text);
                questionSC.scrollTo(0,0);
                RowIndex++;
            }
        }
        @Override public void onLongClick() {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Long click.");
            question.setCursorVisible(true);
            question.performLongClick();
        }
    });
}
```

And the OnSwipeTouchListener class is as the following:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 200;

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    onLongClick();
    super.onLongPress(e);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffX > 0) {
                    onSwipeRight();
                } else {
                    onSwipeLeft();
                }
                result = true;
            }
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
}

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }
   public void onSwipeLeft() {
   }
   public void onSwipeTop() {
   }
   public void onSwipeBottom() {
   }

public void onLongClick() {
}
```

}

I want to be able to select a portion (text) from the TextView and having the swipe detector along it.

**Edited: added the XML file of the mentioned Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_preview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_black_24dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/star_border" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/copy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_content_copy_black_24dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/questionSC"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/question_lo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ge_thameen_book"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you add the xml for that particular TextView as well ?

Comment: sure ... i have edited the post and included the required xml file.
whenever I disable the swipe detection, the Text selection works perfectly.

Comment: Check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47955709/7586266

Comment: Unfortunately the proposed solution is not working ...

Comment: try it using the answer i posted , i altered the textview to actually call the `performLongClick()` on the textView instead of asking for focus or anyhting of that matter as this will guarantee the selectable method to be initiated inside the touchlistener

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a while this is what worked highlighting and selecting text enabling copy,paste,selectall ... etc

you will need to add onTouch snippet in the  `prev_act.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {`

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //do stuff here
                Log.i("clicking", "onActionDown");
            }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                question.performLongClick();
            }

            return false;
        }
        @Override public void onLongClick() {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple:

```
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
```

I had to set the onDown() to return false.